# How to sort Pandas fields based on another value with out loosing date grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, datetime

I currently have a Data Frame that resembles this sample table:

| Date | Model | Horse Power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-05 | Spx | 100 |
|  | P2 | 210 |
|  | G9 | 96 |
| 2019-02-06 | F2 | 111 |
|  | 720S | 720 |
|  | SPY | 450 |

I have attempted to use the sort_by(['Model','Horse Power']) but it returns a key error and if I do sort_by('Horse Power') it ignores the grouping by date and returns all the fields with highest Horse Power.

The output I am attempting to achieve would look something like this:

| Date | Model | Horse Power |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-02-05 | P2 | 210 |
|  | Spx | 100 |
|  | G9 | 96 |
| 2019-02-06 | 720S | 720 |
|  | SPY | 450 |
|  | F2 | 111 |

Comment: `Model` is probably part of a multi-index. Try calling `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` then your `sort_values` call

Comment: `Date` is the index of this DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort_values` and `sort_index` to get your output:

If `Date` is already the index of your dataframe:

```
>>> df.sort_values('Horse Power', ascending=False) \
      .sort_index(kind='mergesort')

           Model  Horse Power
Date
2019-02-05    P2          210
2019-02-05   Spx          100
2019-02-05    G9           96
2019-02-06  720S          720
2019-02-06   SPY          450
2019-02-06    F2          111
```

If `Date` is a column (which doesn't seem to be the case here):

```
>>> df.set_index("Date") \
      .sort_values('Horse Power', ascending=False) \
      .sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index()

         Date Model  Horse Power
0  2019-02-05    P2          210
1  2019-02-05   Spx          100
2  2019-02-05    G9           96
3  2019-02-06  720S          720
4  2019-02-06   SPY          450
5  2019-02-06    F2          111
```

Comment: Im getting a key error for the Date column which mentions duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

Comment: Try `df.sort_values('Horse Power', ascending=False).sort_index()`. What is the output?

Comment: The sort_index _must_ be "mergesort" to maintain the sorted order of the other columns `df.sort_values(by='Horse Power', ascending=False).sort_index(kind='mergesort')`

Comment: Totally agree :-P

Comment: For some reason the output is coming out exactly the same :(

Comment: Update your post with the output of `df.info()`